# error message when doing iteration with ggplot2:"More than one expression parsed"

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I have a data frame with 8 variables, I tried to plot bar plots of 3 variables(discrete variables) in one page using the following script:

```
lyst <- list(colnames(mydata[3:5]))
pl<-lapply(lyst, function(i)ggplot(mydata, aes_string(i)) + geom_bar(aes_string(fill=i)))
marrangeGrob(pl, nrow=2, ncol=2)
```

At first it worked, but now I get the following error message:
 Error: More than one expression parsed
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace.

> rlang::last_error()
>   
>   More than one expression parsed
>   Backtrace:
>
> 1. base::lapply(...)
> 2. global::FUN(X[[i]], ...)
> 3. ggplot2::aes_string(i)
> 4. base::lapply(...)
> 5. ggplot2:::FUN(X[[i]], ...)
> 6. rlang::parse_expr(x).

Any one have an idea how to fix this error?

Comment: Could you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)? For example, if you provide part of you data, I can run the code on my machine and help you :D

Answer (score 0):

For me, the column names of my dataframe contained unwanted characters like semicolons and white spaces. To fix this problem, I cleaned the column names before passing them as strings to `aes_string()`. You can do this with base r's `make.names()` function or using `janitor::clean_names()` before running your code.

**Solution:**

```
# Using base r:

colnames(mydata) <- make.names(colnames(mydata))

# Using Janitor:

install.packages(janitor) # If not already installed

mydata <- janitor::clean_names(mydata)
```